# vim folding with laravel blade templating engine

Tags: vim, laravel, folding, laravel-blade

I am having problem with Vim folding when using laravel blade template engine. It is displaying folding markers on the page. So after refreshing browser window I see **/*{{{*/**

My folding is set to marker - it is the only folding setting in my **.vimrc**.

Anyone knows how to fix that ?
Thanks.

Ok here is update:

After entering verbose commands in vim here is what I got:

```
:verbose set fdm → foldmethod=marker
:verbose set frm? → foldmarker = {{{,}}}
:verbose set fdt? → foldtext=foldtext()
```

I am thinking since blade is based on regex, it can't filter properly foldmarkers ?

Comment: Your framework probably chokes on foldmarkers. Could you post an example?

Comment: Please post some sample code and the output of `:verbose set fdm? fdt? fmr?`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea behind *foldmarkers* is that they are contained in the source code file, but otherwise neutral with regards to the programming language. This usually means that they have to be **contained inside comments**. If you still see them in the browser, that means that you failed to hide them from the template engine.

You need to embed them inside comments, e.g. HTML ones: `<!-- {{{1 -->`. Vim can help you with this (on `zf` - create fold) through the `'commentstring'` option.

Note that *foldmarkers* are mostly only used for personal, custom text files (where you want to create a folding structure without having a proper syntax or other formal structure). For programming languages, you rather use either `syntax`, `expr`, or `indent` foldmethods. This is both easier than managing folds yourself, and it doesn't litter the code with editor-specific rubbish that doesn't belong there (or do your non-Vim-using colleagues like this?!)

In case your template engine is based on HTML, this (when put into `~/.vim/after/syntax/html.vim`, together with `:setlocal foldmethod=syntax` should give you some folding:

```
:syntax region htmlFold start="<\z(p\|h\d\|table\|colgroup\|thead\|tfoot\|tbody\|t[dhr]\|pre\|[diou]l\|li\|span\|div\|head\|script\|style\|blockquote\|form\)\%(\_s*\_[^/]\?>\|\_s\_[^>]*\_[^>/]>\)" end="</\z1\_s*>" fold transparent keepend extend containedin=htmlHead,htmlH\d
```